# Angular make dynamic tooltip message

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

- I want to make one tooltip component for If my application running on Development mode than tooltip will show in my project but in Production mode this will not display.
- In tooltip I want to show calculation on particular field like I have one control which calculate Control A and Control B value so When I go to this control tooltip than I want to show "Control A + Control B" So in my application I will identify all control calculations. I am using Angular 16 please suggest me way.

**calcualtion.ts**

```
    export class Calculations {
    static calculateNetAmount(form: FormGroup) {
        let retVal: number = form.controls['totalAmount'].value - form.controls['totalTaxAmount'].value
        form.controls['netAmount'].setValue(retVal);
    }
}
```

**html:**

```
<input type="number" formControlName="netAmount">
```

- Here I want to show one tooltip above the input tag and this tooltip contains string message like "NetAmount = TotalAmount - TotalTaxAmount"
- I have 100 plus static Function in my Calculations class so I want each and every control identify with specific message so please suggest me way to display this messages dynamically.

Comment: can you please share some work sample, it will be easier to troubleshoot and assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by below ways:

```
export class Calculations {
    public setFormulaTooltip(form:FormGroup,fieldName:string,information:string){
        const control = form.get(fieldName) as FormControl; 
        //@ts-ignore       
        control['tooltip'] = information ;
    }
    static calculateNetAmount(form: FormGroup) {
        let retVal: number = form.controls['totalAmount'].value - form.controls['totalTaxAmount'].value;
        this.setFormulaTooltip(form,'netAmount','totalAmount - totalTaxAmount');
        form.controls['netAmount'].setValue(retVal);
    }
}
```

Write function for calculate values & set message for control.

### Html FOR COMMON COMPONENT

```
<img src="../../../../../assets/images/svg/Fields/Areyousure-blue.svg" class="formula" 
     matTooltip="{{this.tooltipMessage}}" *ngIf="this.tooltipMessage" />
<input type="number" formControlName="netAmount">
```

Need to give imge for display tooltip message when message string available.

### .ts File FOR COMMON COMPONENT

```
this.parentFormGroup.controls[this.formDisplayFieldName].valueChanges.subscribe((data: any) => {
    //@ts-ignore
    if(this.parentFormGroup!.get(this.formDisplayFieldName)['tooltip']){
        //@ts-ignore
        this.tooltipMessage = this.parentFormGroup!.get(this.formDisplayFieldName)['tooltip']
    }
});
```

when your form value change then need to set tooltip message.

Comment: the path of your img is **wrong**. Should be `src="assets/images/svg/Fields/Areyousure-blue.svg"`. Think that it's not logic that, if you change the component from one folder to another one, you'll need change all the src of your images

Comment: that image is not main point, instead of image you can assume  any icon but main thing is core logic behind dynamic content rendering.

Comment: Parth, it was only an advice (I don't make any comment about your code although I think you should use get method in all the code to make more consistent -sometimes you use get, and sometimes controls)

Comment: oh thank you for advice. might be i need to use get in all place instead of control. thanks again for your valuables suggestion